# Word count of selection in a PDF file

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer

I am looking for a PDF viewer that can give a word count of a selected text.

It should work on Microsoft Windows. Gratis is preferable.

Comment: You can count it with *Adobe Acrobat Pro*, just that it doesn't calculate automatically when you select the text.

Comment: @PichiWuana how do you count in Adobe Acrobat Pro,? http://rlab-it-blog.blogspot.com/2014/07/word-count-in-pdfs-using-acrobat-pro.html seems to say is not so straightforward.

Comment: Word 2013/2016 can open PDF files also show the word count in the footer. It shows selected word count also in the footer.

Comment: @DavisJebaraj Good point, you're welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word 2013/2016 can open PDF files and also show the word count in the footer. It shows selected word count also in the footer.

Comment: Never new this! What a great options for editing pdfs too!